# How to remove a table's row from jquery dialog table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is jquery dialog (#dialog-message1) where table (tableINFO) is append. 
Each row of the table shows some information regarding product with a picture link in last column.
I would like to create an on-click event where some actions are taken i.e. table row deletion and (potrawy1Engine.php) script call. 
I tried creating (.confirmation2),but it does not work as expected - link is followed instead.

Can somebody help me and advice on the js script, please?

What I would like to do is to delete a row in the table tableINFO, where a link was clicked after it was clicked.

.confirmation1 and .confirmation work fine, only .confirmation2 does not work.
Maybe the problem is that the table and the link are created dynamically in jquery?

Here is the js:

```
$("#dialog-message").hide();

$('.confirmation').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location.href = lnk;
                },
                Anuluj: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
        }
    });
});

$("#dialog-message1").hide();

$('.confirmation1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();

    $( "#dialog-message1" ).hide();
    $( "#dialog-message1 table" ).remove();
    $( "#dialog-message1 #labelINFO" ).remove();

    $("#dialog-message1").append("<table id='tableINFO'> </table>"); 
    $("#dialog-message1 table").append("<tr><th  width='350px' >Nazwa produktu</th><th width='70px'>Waga (g)</th><th  width='100px'>Kalorie (Kcal)</th> <th  width='80px'>Białko (g)</th> <th  width='90px'>Tłuszcze (g)</th><th  width='120px'>Węglowodany (g)</th><th  width='30px'> </th> </tr>");

    $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "potrawyINFOEngine.php",
            data: {"nazwa": product_name},
    }).done(function( data ) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            var len = result.length;        
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                var T_nazwaproduktu = result[i].produkt;
                var T_waga = result[i].waga;
                var T_kalorie = result[i].kalorie;
                var T_bialko = result[i].bialko;
                var T_tluszcze = result[i].tluszcze;
                var T_weglowodany = result[i].weglowodany;
                var tr_str = "<tr>" +
                            "<td align='left'>" + T_nazwaproduktu + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='right'>" + T_waga + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='right'>" + T_kalorie + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='right'>" + T_bialko + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='right'>" + T_tluszcze + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='right'>" + T_weglowodany + "</td>" +
                            "<td align='center'>" + 
                            "<a href='usunProduktPotrawa.php?nazwaPotrawy=" + product_name + "&nazwaProduktu=" + T_nazwaproduktu + "' title='Usuń produkt' class='confirmation2'><img src='pictures/cross16.jpg' width='10' height='10' style='margin: 0px 0px' /></a>" ;
                            "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";
            $("#dialog-message1 table").append(tr_str);
            }
        console.log(data);
    });

    $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "potrawyINFOOpisEngine.php",
                data: {"nazwa": product_name},
    }).done(function( data ) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(result);
                $("#dialog-message1").append("<label id='labelINFO'>" + result + "</label>");
    $( "#dialog-message1" ).show();

    });

    $("#dialog-message1").dialog({
        height: "auto",
            width: 950,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
            $( "#dialog-message1 table" ).remove();
            $( "#dialog-message1 #labelINFO" ).remove();
                }
            }
    });
});

$("#dialog-message2").hide();

$('.confirmation2').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();

    $( "#dialog-message2" ).hide();

    $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "potrawy1Engine.php",
                data: {"nazwa": product_name},
    }).done(function( data ) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(result);
                $( "#dialog-message2" ).show();
    });

    $("#dialog-message2").dialog({
        height: "auto",
            width: 450,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
    });
});
```

HTML part is here:

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Usuwanie potrawy">
        <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-help" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>Czy chcesz usunąć wybraną potrawe?
        </p>
        <p>
        Naciśnij OK aby kontynuować.
        </p>
</div>

<div id="dialog-message1" title="Składniki i opis potrawy">
</div>

<div id="dialog-message2" title="Test">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please scale this down to only a minimum representation of the problem. See [mcve]. The php code and db queries for example are not relevant to the problem

Comment: I have cut out some html part. js code is more then less important as it is.